# How to solve this percentage expenditure consumption problem in more easy way?

Tags: percentages

The price of rice is increased by 20%, By what percentage should the consumption be reduced so that the expenditure on rice remains the same?

My sir told me this method:

physical units consumed = $c$.

price per physical unit = $p$.

total amount expended = $t=p∗c$.

$(p + \Delta p)(c + \Delta c)$ = $t$

$\implies$ $\Delta p$ = $20\% \text { of } p$ $\implies$ $\Delta p$ = $0.2p$ $\implies$ $(p + \Delta p)$ = $1.2p$

$\implies$ $1.2p(c + \Delta c)$ = $t \implies (c + \Delta c)$ = $\dfrac{t}{1.2p}$ = $\dfrac{p * c}{1.2p} = \dfrac{c}{1.2}$

**Is there any easy method to solve this problem?**

Ans: 16 (2/3)% (mixed fraction)

Comment: Your method is correct and is already the most efficient way

Comment: you commented so fast. why hurry? Think slowly and re-read the question.

Comment: uh because it’s a simple question...